# How to use interface as a criteria to a filter in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Please forgive me, I'm a javascript developer trying to learn typescript.  In a challenge I've hit a snag.

So, I've got some interfaces and a tray of objects (data) and I'm trying to use the interface as a criteria in a filter function, but the type 'Cat' is not defined.  I tried exporting it, but it brought other errors.

interfaces:

```
interface Cat {
   type: 'cat';
   name: string;
   hunts?: string;
}

interface Fish {
   type: 'fish'
   name: string;
   hides?: string;
}

export type Animal = Cat | Fish;
export const isCat = (animal: Animal): animal is Cat => animal.type === 'cat';
export const isFish = (animal: Animal): animal is Fish => animal.type === 'fish';
```

data:

```
import { Animal} from '../interface/species';

export const pets: Animal[] = [
{
    type: 'cat',
    name: 'Mr Whiskers',
    hunts: 'mice'
},
{
    type: 'fish',
    name: 'bubbles',
    hides: 'castle'
}
];
```

my trouble is with this filter function:

```
export function filterAnimal(animal: Animal[], criteria: Cat): Cat[] {
    return animal.filter((pet) => {
        for (var key in pet) {
            if (pet[key] === criteria)
                return pet; 
        }
    });
}
```

How can I use Cat as the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Types and interfaces are a part of typescript and they get removed during complication, so you cannot access them at runtime directly.

However, you can use a property which identifies you type. In your case, it looks like each `Cat` has `type === "cat"`, so in your filter you could do:

```
export function filterAnimal(animals: Animal[], type: "cat" | "dog"): Animal[] {
  return animals.filter((animal) => animal.type === type);
}
```

If you'd like a function that specifically filters `Cats`, you can do so similarly:

```
export function getOnlyCats(animals: Animal[]): Animal[] {
  return animals.filter((animal) => animal.type === "cat");
}
```

---

Now, in some cases you may need to rely on the fact that your function only returns instances of the `Cat` type. For example, you want to print what the cat hunts without errors. In this case, you'll need to manually assert that the function in fact returns an array of `Cat` objects, by casting the return type.

```
function getOnlyCats(animals: Animal[]): Cat[] {
  return (animals.filter((animal) => animal.type === "cat")) as Cat[];
}

// now you can safely do
const cats = getOnlyCats(animals);
cats.forEach(cat => {
  if (cat.hunts) {
    console.log(`cat ${cat.name} hunts ${cat.hunts}.`)
  } else {
    console.log(`cat ${cat.hunts} doesn't hunt.`)
  }
});
```

Check out a [live example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzMg3gKGfsATwAcIAuZAcgQ0oG498Q4Bbc5AZzClAHMH8yABYBXcBwD8FLjxD8cAXxw5QkWIhQAxYByHZGyIqQqUYOoZQPM207nwH4hwACYRJt2fKU4jKAIIgwCxwADbIALxoGMgAPsjaugwIAPYgXMg66JiRABRwgcEhFAFBoQCUFPmlYTpR2QB8yFWFAHS+EeGR1LRJqek6CXq5zaHFBeWV4zUc8eYRjSMhbSQonV1muvTKMGIIYMCpyLwQYADyICGEWRx5Uxxj1QDaALoVdS-6+FAnIlAgyLdqhwWmYQmocoDCmV5k0pstSB1IgAiGhgJFlaFwGZZF4MbwpNKYRb3ZAlQofSKPRi4QSGFYUFEYJEAGgMyGs7CRbGSAHdCCy2aJxAyWMAkAL8ApmchqWzfAyNkIJYIOQyAEYiEJq5VS2W0+XIRlo1m01WGjgIKAiGAwEJuZWOMRgEmMqAcHXSnDPBg4AnpVEzSLHM4XK4YG7EspJcMg5JQACiiCEOVRMJpGRgANRLSFzuh6fwfuSdpaIWSvByAANUwASLDZjkKYROmZ17O5jgKFqVsqMJsQEIcFAF5BFktlivV6JtjA5ltN5zJNwgSiYXPd3uSxRRoA).

Comment: I'm getting a complaint from VS Code saying "type Cat = /*unresolved*/ any"

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan where? i edited my answer with a live example, you can see it works there.

Comment: I was trying to keep the criteria parameter.   Ultimately, the question is how to handle a parameter that is a interface passed as a type.

Comment: In the first approach with 'type: "cat" | "dog"' as the parameter, this does not work since neither are types, interfaces

Comment: you cannot pass an interface as an argument to a function. functions are called at runtime, after your code is complied to javascript. there are no interfaces in javascript.

Comment: ah, hence why try are using a pre-screen (getCatsOnly) before?